# MySQL Not Null commands aren't doing anything

Tags: mysql, sql, null

I'm just starting SQL and I'm trying to change a tables values from NULL to NOT NULL, except the command prompt is showing that it isn't being changed.

Here's the code I'm putting in:

```
CREATE TABLE my_contacts
(
    last_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    gender CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    birthday DATE NOT NULL,
    profession VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    location VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    status VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    interests VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    seeking VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

I can't post images but when I use DESC my_contacts; the table prints out and shows "Yes" under the null column for all rows.

This is MySQL 5.6

Comment: I've tried to execute your DDL script and when I've run desc command that's all OK. All columns are NOT NULLABLE. Show http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/41cd4/1/0

Comment: Are you trying to change the existing table or just recreating it?

Comment: Just realized what I was doing, I'm trying to EDIT a table, not create one. How can I do that?

Comment: But your script starts with.... CREATE TABLE...

Comment: you will have to do an `alter table` command for each column. or just drop the table then recreate it. It will be easier

Answer (score 1):

So as you mentioned in your comments. Do as follow:

But remeber one thing. If you create the table and have inserted some data on it and left any of the columns that you want to change to `not null` you will have to delete the data or put some data on the field that is null.

```
alter table my_contacts modify last_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL;
alter table my_contacts modify first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL;
alter table my_contacts modify email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL;
alter table my_contacts modify gender CHAR(1) NOT NULL;
alter table my_contacts modify birthday DATE NOT NULL;
alter table my_contacts modify profession VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL;
alter table my_contacts modify location VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL;
alter table my_contacts modify status VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL;
alter table my_contacts modify interests VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL;
alter table my_contacts modify seeking VARCHAR(100) NOT NULl;
```

Or if it suits better:

```
drop table my_contacts;

CREATE TABLE my_contacts
(
    last_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    gender CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    birthday DATE NOT NULL,
    profession VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    location VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    status VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    interests VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    seeking VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```